# Cannot assign value of type '[Session]?' to type '[Session]?'

Tags: swift

I don't understand this error because it says I cannot assign value of type X to X, on the assignment self.dados[key] = data[key]. My code is the following:

```
class SessionListController: UITableViewController, RepositorySessionsDelegate {

var dados: [String:[Session]] = [String:[Session]]()

func didReturnData<Session>(data: [String:[Session]]) {
    let keys = data.keys
    self.dados.removeAll()
    for key in keys {
        self.dados[key] = data[key]
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? The types seem correct and the error doesn't seem valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your function. First why the "<"Session">". Second you seem to just wanna swap the values of dados for the new data, why not just assign the new data to dados? If you wanna use your function just remove "<"Session">".

```
var dados: [String: [Session]] = [String: [Session]]()

func didReturnData(data: [String: [Session]]) {
    let keys = data.keys
    dados.removeAll()
    for key in keys {
       dados[key] = data[key]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

didReturnData < Session >

You are using a generic type < Session > in this method, this way Session inside your method is not the same as Session outside your method. You can't use "< Session >" here.

You can read more about generic parameters here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html